# The method andExpect(ResultMatcher) in the type ResultActions is not applicable for the arguments (RequestMatcher)

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I am working on the `Spring MVC + Mockito` and I have developed the below code which is causing the error not sure what is wrong.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import com.memorynotfound.config.WebConfig;
import com.memorynotfound.controller.UserController;
import com.memorynotfound.filter.CORSFilter;
import com.memorynotfound.model.User;
import com.memorynotfound.service.UserService;


@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebConfig.class})
public class UserControllerUnitTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private UserService userService;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserController userController;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(userController).addFilters(new CORSFilter()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test_get_all_success() throws Exception{
        List<User> users = Arrays.asList(
                new User(1, "Daenerys Targaryen"),
                new User(2, "John Snow"));

        when(userService.getAll()).thenReturn(users);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/users"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id", is(1)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].username", is("Daenerys Targaryen")))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].id", is(2)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].username", is("John Snow")));

        verify(userService, times(1)).getAll();
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(userService);
    }
}
```

I suspect, something related to the import statement not working.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    // =========================================== Get All Users ==========================================

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAll() {
        LOG.info("getting all users");
        List<User> users = userService.getAll();

        if (users == null || users.isEmpty()){
            LOG.info("no users found");
            return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Here is the error for reference:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method andExpect(ResultMatcher) in the type ResultActions is not applicable for the arguments (RequestMatcher)
    The method hasSize(int) is undefined for the type UserControllerUnitTest
    The method is(int) is undefined for the type UserControllerUnitTest
    The method is(String) is undefined for the type UserControllerUnitTest
    The method is(int) is undefined for the type UserControllerUnitTest
    The method is(String) is undefined for the type UserControllerUnitTest
    The method times(int) is undefined for the type UserControllerUnitTest

    at com.memorynotfound.test.UserControllerUnitTest.test_get_all_success(UserControllerUnitTest.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I should have used this:**

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import com.memorynotfound.config.WebConfig;
import com.memorynotfound.controller.UserController;
import com.memorynotfound.filter.CORSFilter;
import com.memorynotfound.model.User;
import com.memorynotfound.service.UserService;
```

Comment: By me the problem with andExpect() was:
`import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.content;` I had to remove it. I see you removed it as well. It was added by Eclipse in my case.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. I  discovered that there are two content classes; one for request and the other for result.

```
org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.content;
    org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
```

eclipse automatically imported the first MockRestRequestMatchers.content. The right class is MockMvcResultMatchers.content.

If you add the following import and delete the one imported by Eclipse. It should work.

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two tipes of content classes (request, response). If you want to fix quickly and add all the methods you have to import:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
```